# Authentication results in 404 code

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, lxml, access-token

There is a website I  need to scrape, but before I do I need to login.

There seems to be three things I need to get in, the username, password and authenticity token.  The user name and password I know, but I am not sure how to access the token.

This is what I have tried:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

login_url = "https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/home"

session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]

payload = {"username": "my_name",
           "password": "my_password",
           "authenticity_token": authenticity_token}

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

print (result)
```

This results in :

`<Response [404]>`

My name and password are entered correctly so it is the token that must be going wrong.  I think the problem is this line:

`authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]`

or this line:

```
payload = {"username": "my_name",
               "password": "my_password",
               "authenticity_token": authenticity_token}
```

by looking at the source code on the webpage I noticed there is a `authenticity_token`, `csrf-token` and a `csrf-param`.  So its possible these are in the wrong order, but I tried all the combinations.

EDIT:

Here is a beautiful soup approach that results in 404 again.

```
s = requests.session()                                                         
response = s.get(login_url)   

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")                                            
for n in soup('input'): 
    if n['name'] == 'authenticity_token':                                             
        token = n['value'] 
    if n['name'] == 'utf8':
        utf8 = n['value']                                               
        break

auth = {                                                                       
    'username': 'my_username'                                                       
    , 'password': 'my_password'                                                 
    , 'authenticity_token': token    
    , 'utf8' : utf8                                                 
}    

s.post(login_url, data=auth)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the page you'll notice that form action value is `'/login'`, so you have to submit your data to `https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login'`.

```
login_url = "https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/login"
home_url = "https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/home"

s = requests.session()                                                         
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(home_url).text, "lxml")                                            
data = {i['name']:i.get('value', '') for i in soup.find_all('input')}
data['username'] = 'my_username'
data['password'] = 'my_password'
result = s.post(login_url, data=data)

print(result)
```

> < Response [200]>

A quick example with [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/MOST/MOD10A1.006/'

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('my_username')
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('my_password')
driver.find_element_by_id('login').submit()

html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

Comment: there is another page I really want to access is `https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/MOST/MOD10A1.006/`.  After the data is posted to login_url is there a way to maintain session or repost to that link to?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the login is successful you should be able to use the session to access other pages. I can't verify that because i don't have an account yet (it takes up to 48 hours to activate new accounts) but you could try with 'Referer' and 'User-Agent' in the headers. If you still can't login you could try `selenium`.

Comment: Yea I just used `s.get()` again on the new link and I followed a redirect page and It worked.